# Make a video from an NSArray of NSImages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsimage

I know this has been asked before, but the only answers I have found use UIImages. I need to make a 25 fps video from an NSArray of NSImages in Objective-C. Could somebody give me a link to the documentation dealing with this (if there is any), or tell me how I can do it?

NOTE: I will also need to know which frameworks to use if there is no documentation on this. And, before you ask, I have done lots of searches for the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [QTKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) by creating a movie and adding images as frames. See the "[Creating a Single Frame-Grabbing Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW34)" section. Step 13 specifically demonstrates how to add an image (and have it last a specific duration in the movie ... should probably last more than a single frame for, say, stop-motion stuff).